# Does there exist continuous functions $P$ and $Q$ on [0,1]

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Does there exist continuous functions  $P$ and $Q$ on $[0,1]$ such that $y(t)=sin(t^2)$  is a solution to $y''+Py'+Qy=0$ on $[\frac1n,1]$ for all $n\geq1$?

I find $y'$ and $y''$ and compare with the given differential equation and found that $P(t)= -1/t$ and which is not continuous on [0,1]. So such function $P$ can not exist.

Is my concept is correct . Please help me to solve this also if any other method .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are $P$ and $Q$ allowed to depend on $n$? If so, then the answer is "yes" (you can modify $P$ on $[0,\frac1n]$ so it is continuous). If not, then the answer is "no" for the reason you gave. But why then did you mention $n$? Why not just say on $(0,1]$?

Comment: Just plug in the solution $y$ and conditions for $P$ and $Q$ should come from that.

I got $P(t) = -1/t$ and $Q(t) = 4t^2$. They are both continuous on (0,1]

Comment: It is given on the question.  I did not think it before. Are P and Q allowed to depend on n or not. Is the question is correct?  @Jason

Comment: But there given closed interval [0,1] sir. @Gregory

Comment: Where did you find this question? Could you please write it out exactly as written? The order of words matters. If, for instance, it asks "For each $n\ge1$, does there exist... such that... on $[\frac1n,1]$?" then the answer is YES. As you have written, the answer is no, but the inclusion of the "on $[\frac1n,1]$ for all $n\ge1$" is a red flag for me, since any sensible author would instead just write "on $(0,1]$".

Comment: I have got the question from ISI MMATH 2017 question paper @Jason

Answer (score 2):

Your differential equation gives
$$(2 t P(t)+2) \cos \left(t^2\right)+\left(Q(t)-4 t^2\right) \sin \left(t^2\right)=0$$
Demanding that $(2 t P(t)+2)$ and $\left(Q(t)-4 t^2\right)$ are 0 for all $t$ gives the solution that you already know, with $P(t)=-1/t$.

But what if they aren't zero for all $t$? Rearranging a bit
$$\frac{\cos \left(t^2\right)}{\sin \left(t^2\right)}=-\frac{Q(t)-4 t^2}{2 t P(t)+2 } $$
The l.h.s. has a singularity at $t=0$. Assuming $Q(t)$ is continuous in $[0,1]$, the denominator in the r.h.s. must have a 0 at $t=0$, which is not possible for continuous $P(t)$.

Comment: Thank you sir @Wouter